# Fatal error: Call to a member function getProduct() on a non-object in

Tags: shopping-cart

I have this problem for a couple of years now and I don't know how to fix it.

When customers have something in the shopping cart and they want to delete it after some time, they sometimes get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getProduct() on a non-object in /home/user../../CartController.php online 95
```

On line 95 on that file it says:

```
$productId = $this->_getCart()->getQuote()->getItemById($id)->getProduct()->getId();
```

Can somebody please help me? So the problem shows only after deleting a product after a while and not always.

Comment: Where does `$id` come from? Do you only need this one item or could you loop through the cart?

Comment: You get this error on attempting to remove items that have been deleted from the product catalog?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found such a line of code in the default `CartController`. If this is a custom code most probably it was done wrong.
To overcome this change

```
$productId = $this->_getCart()->getQuote()->getItemById($id)->getProduct()->getId();
```

to

```
$item = $this->_getCart()->getQuote()->getItemById($id);
if ($item) {
    $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId(); //or better yet $item->getProductId();
}
else {
    $productId = false; //it means the item was not found and you should handle this case differently.
}
```

Comment: Summary: Test for existence of item in Product Catalog, it may have been deleted. `Call to a member function getProduct() on a non-object` indicates that `getProduct()` isn't finding anything when it goes to look for the specific ID.